# How to read child or filter firebase data by its key value in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to both swift and firebase , I'm trying to get all the item and price printed using this code below , I want to be able to print ..

output :

- Red Chair 100
- Sofa Bed  120

[image]

```
  var ref =  Firebase(url: "https://jeanniefirstapp.firebaseio.com")

var item1     =  ["name": "Alan Turning", "item" : "Red Chair", "price": "100"]
var item2     =  ["name": "Grace Hopper", "item": "Sofa Bed"  , "price": "120"]
var item3     =  ["name": "James Cook"  , "item": "White Desk", "price": "250"]
var item4     =  ["name": "James Cook"  , "item": "Mattress Cal King", "price": "100"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var usersRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("users")

    var users = ["item1": item1, "item2": item2, "item3" : item3 , "item4" : item4 ]

    usersRef.setValue(users)


}
ref.queryOrderedByChild("price").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let price = snapshot.value["price"] as? Int {
        println("\(snapshot.key) price at \(price) Dollars ")
        println(snapshot.key)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to execute the same code for each item, you'll want to use `.ChildAdded`:

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("price").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
  if let price = snapshot.value["price"] as? Int {
    println("\(snapshot.key) price at \(price) Dollars ")
    println(snapshot.key)
  }
})
```

See the [page on retrieving data in the Firebase guide for iOS developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) for more information and examples.

### Update

I ended up using your code in a local xcode and see there are two problems. So all three combined:

1. you are listening for the `.Value` event, but your block is dealing with a single item at a time. Solution:

   ```
   ref.queryOrderedByChild("price")
      .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
   ```
2. you are listening for the `.Value` event at the top-level, but you are adding the items under `users`. Solution:

   ```
   ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
      .queryOrderedByChild("price")
      .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
   ```
3. you are testing whether the price is an `Int`, but are adding them as strings. Solution:

   ```
   var item1     =  ["name": "Alan Turning", "item" : "Red Chair", "price": 100]
   var item2     =  ["name": "Grace Hopper", "item": "Sofa Bed"  , "price": 120]
   var item3     =  ["name": "James Cook"  , "item": "White Desk", "price": 250]
   var item4     =  ["name": "James Cook"  , "item": "Mattress Cal King", "price": 100]
   ```

With those changes, the code prints out these results for me:

```
item1 price at 100 Dollars 
item1
item4 price at 100 Dollars 
item4
item2 price at 120 Dollars 
item2
item3 price at 250 Dollars 
item3
```

Comment: hi i have tried that, but I could not find it return <null> ..  do I have to change ref to point to a different location ? I have tried to point to a different location ? I have read that document , but still couldn't get it right.

Comment: I just ran your code in xcode locally. There are two problems. I'll update my answer (will make it easier to read).

Comment: also instead of showing "item1" ( key ) , what is the best way I can call "item" ( value ) => "Red Chair" along with the price ?  so my out put would be like  => Red Chair price at 100 Dollars ( instead of item1 )

Comment: This is a Q&A forum, not a troubleshooting chat channel. Ask one, specific question at a time.

Comment: how to remove a item??

Comment: Great answer. but my question is what if the user is dynamic? like user1, user2 and so on.?